# python 2.7 Tk change label to carry file name from opened file

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code in python 2.7 using `tkinter` that creates a `Button` on a `Frame` to open a file.  There's a `Label` under it.  I'm trying to make it so once the file is opened, the label prints the path, "file1.name" or whatever, on the `Label`, and if you open a new file it will change that `Label` again.

Also, I'm betting there's a better way to move data between the functions than I'm using here with `global`, but that's not worrying me right now.

I have to move the data from the opened files between functions so that I can mix the data and save to a new file. The code is:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
import tkFileDialog
import tkMessageBox
root = Tkinter.Tk()
global rfile1
global rfile2
rfile1 = ""
rfile2 = ""
class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets1()
        self.createLabels1()
        self.createWidgets2()
        self.createLabels2()

    def createWidgets1(self):
        self.oButton = Button(self, text = "open1", command = self.openfile1)
        self.oButton.grid()

    def createLabels1(self):
        self.oLabel = Label(self, text = "whoops")
        self.oLabel.grid()

    def createWidgets2(self):
        self.oButton = Button(self, text = "open2", command= self.openfile2)
        self.oButton.grid()

    def createLabels2(self):
        self.oLabel2 = Label(self, text = "whoops2")
        self.oLabel2.grid()

    def openfile1(self):
        file1 = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(title = "choose a file, *****", parent=root, mode = 'rb')

        rfile1 = file1.read()
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("oy", rfile1, parent=root)

    def openfile2(self):
        file2 = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(parent=root, mode='rb')

        rfile2 = file2.read()
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("hola", rfile2, parent=root)

app = Application()
app.master.title("whiggy whompus")
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want something like (*untested*):

```
def openfile1(self):
    file1 = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(title = "choose a file, *****", parent=root, mode = 'rb')
    self.oLabel.configure(text=file1.name)    
    rfile1 = file1.read()
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("oy", rfile1, parent=root)
```

Answer (score 0):

@mgilson has solved your first question. Your second question, about how to pass parameters between functions without using globals :

you might want to look at storing the variables as attributes on your application class :

The syntax self. is an attribute on the current instance (an instance being a particular example of a class - just like your car is a specific example of a class "car").
You can use instance attributes in this example as if they are globals.

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
import tkFileDialog
import tkMessageBox
root = Tkinter.Tk()

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets1()
        self.createLabels1()
        self.createWidgets2()
        self.createLabels2()
        self.rfile1 = ""
        self.rfile2 = ""

    def createWidgets1(self):
       self.oButton = Button(self, text = "open1", command = self.openfile1)
       self.oButton.grid()

    def createLabels1(self):
        self.oLabel = Label(self, text = "whoops")
        self.oLabel.grid()

    def createWidgets2(self):
        self.oButton = Button(self, text = "open2", command= self.openfile2)
        self.oButton.grid()

    def createLabels2(self):
        self.oLabel2 = Label(self, text = "whoops2")
        self.oLabel2.grid()

    def openfile1(self):
        file1 = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(title = "choose a file, *****", parent=root, mode = 'rb')

        self.rfile1 = file1.read()
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("oy", self.rfile1, parent=root)

    def openfile2(self):
        file2 = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(parent=root, mode='rb')

        self.rfile2 = file2.read()
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("hola", self.rfile2, parent=root)

app = Application()
app.master.title("whiggy whompus")
app.mainloop()
```